# Doctrine migrations wont recognise changes to annotations (in production)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

**The original problem**

The reasons, notes and members fields bellow where `@ORM\Column(type="string", length=20000)` which did not work because that is too long for a VARCHAR so I changed them all to `@ORM\Column(type="text")`

**And Now**

It is possible that I have misunderstood the correct way to handle migrations in productions but I can't get my database to match my entity. Running `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` or `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` doctrine tries to update the database to an old version of Request.php like it has been cached but even after running clear-metadata the migrations all say `VARCHAR(20000)` like in this sql dump after I manually changed the database:

```
ALTER TABLE request CHANGE reasons reasons VARCHAR(20000) NOT NULL, CHANGE notes notes VARCHAR(20000) DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE members members VARCHAR(20000) NOT NULL;
```

Current Request.php

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\RequestRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=RequestRepository::class)
 */
class Request
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="time")
     * @Assert\LessThan(propertyPath="endTime", message="The booking must start before it ends")
     */
    private $startTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="time")
     */
    private $endTime;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $reasons;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $notes;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="requests")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $members;
```

I have tried removing the Request.php entity but then doctrine gets upset that it is gone. (I do have a relational link to the user table here but it is one to many).

Changing the names of members reasons and notes worked but when I changed the names back it wanted to set them back to `VARCHAR(20000)`. Where is it holding this info. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: it's probably part of the cache. when you clear the cache (and warming it back up), symfony runs "compiler passes" that among other things read annotations and build metadata and stuff, also for doctrine and so on. So I would first try to run `bin/console cache:clear` and see if that changes stuff.

Comment: Thank you this cleared it. I knew it was cached somewhere. How do I mark this question as resolved?

Comment: you can mark the answer I just posted as the solution ;o)

Comment: Thank you Jakumi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine Metadata is cached. When you clear the cache (and warming it back up), symfony runs "compiler passes" that among other things read annotations to build the metadata, proxy objects, registers repositories, all this kind of stuff (obviously other doctrine-unrelated stuff as well).

Running `bin/console cache:clear` *should* solve your problems. (It also should be part of your deployment process. And unless you copy over the vendor dir as well, `composer install` too).